# Download List of Currently Registered Devices from Apple

Tags: ios, provisioning

Is there a way I could download the list of all my currently registered devices (Provisioning Portal), Im afraid downloading/saving the page as html doesn't help because it the UDID's has ellipsis at the end, likewise there is no button to export it to text/excel,

Is it possible?

TIA

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to solve. Use chrome and command A on a mac while in edit mode. Use shift to remove the unwanted highlighting at the top. Paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is naturally truncated and an ellipsis is appended at the end of the UDID, maybe because Apple does not seem to see a valid reason for its users to play with the UDID's, but requirements come and go, so here's what I did;

Instead of figuring out how to extract the UDID's from the portal tab "Currently Registered Devices", go to History instead, using VIM copy the required contents from the page, and use VIM to do the dirty job for you, add/remove unnecessary info, and presto you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Create a new provisioning profile, add all devices ("Select All"), "Modify" the profile and view the page source, you will find all devices and their UDID there.

You can do the same on the device page, UDIDs are complete in source, they are cut off by the page layout.

Comment: but this will add unnecessary clog to your list of available provisioning, while they are complete in the source, there is still a dilemma of how to extract it into excel/text file format.

Comment: yes you will have to parse that information.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow that Link: [StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29426740/2905967)

You just have to write following code in JavaScript Console in your Google Chrome Browser after moving to your developer account's page device list page.

```
var ids = ["Device ID"];
var names = ["Device Name"];
$("td[aria-describedby=grid-table_name]").each(function(){
    names.push($(this).html());
});
$("td[aria-describedby=grid-table_deviceNumber]").each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).html());
});

var output = "";
for (var index = 0; index < ids.length; index++) {
    //output += names[index] + "\t" + ids[index] + "\n";    //original
    output += ids[index] + "\t" + names[index] + "\n";      //post September 2016
}
console.log(output);
```